# Angular ng options group by

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a json structure that i need help to set an select field with his structure and group by his fields.

In my scope:

```
this.cols = jsonData;
```

This is the json:

```
[
  {
    "name": [
      {"displayName": "First Name", "modelName": "firstName"},
      {"displayName": "Last Name", "modelName": "lastName"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "address": [
      {"displayName": "Zip Code", "modelName": "zipCode"},
      {"displayName": "city", "modelName": "city"}
    ]
  }
]
```

What i need the select will look like this:

```
-name (the group name)
First Name(displayName) and track by modelName
Last Name(displayName) and track by modelName
-address (the group name)
Zip Code(displayName) and track by modelName
city(displayName) and track by modelName
```

I know how to do a simple ng options but not like this, please help.

Comment: If you can transform the json (maybe on-load) to have a *flat* list with the group name as a property on each value, you could use the *native* `group by` syntax. Is that an option?

Comment: Yes, that what id did, but the track by modelName dont work.

Comment: Also with regards to your comment below, do you mean to value in the rendered html? If so, then, unless you submit the form traditionally, you should not be bothered by it. Angular using a numeric value is an implemenation detail, which should not be a concern to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your array to this structure:

```
$scope.rows = [
    {"group": "name", "displayName": "First Name", "modelName": "firstName"},
    {"group": "name", "displayName": "Last Name", "modelName": "lastName"},
    {"group": "address", "displayName": "Zip Code", "modelName": "zipCode"},
    {"group": "address", "displayName": "city", "modelName": "city"}
]
```

Then you can use `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model="row" ng-options="row.modelName as row.displayName group by row.group for row in rows"></select>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D53X5Q1XgMmvEh2KJ5P2)

Comment: The value is still the $index

Comment: You are doing it in non-angular way. You can't use `value` property of `<select>`, but use `ng-model`ed variable `$scope.row` instead.

Comment: You are right, but why the track by is exists in ng-options? this change the value on the options.

Comment: When you use `track by`, whole object is assigned to `ng-model`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it using `ng-options` directive, but you can do this:

```
<select>
 <optgroup ng-repeat="(k,v) in cols" label="k">
    <option ng-repeat="option in v">{{option.displayName}}</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

`(k,v)` in `ng-repeat` stands for key-value pair.